# why does .replace method use forward slash characters to enclose the first argument?

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax

I am working through a book about Javascript and have encountered the following example of code designed to replace the value of the class attribute of a table header HTML element:

`th.className = th.className.replace(/asc/,"dsc");`
`th.className = th.className.replace(/dsc/,"asc");`

Why is the first parameter of .replace, the current value of `th.className`, enclosed in forward slashes instead of quotation marks?

Why not use quotation marks to enclose both parameters, not just the second one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). You can use either regular expressions or strings to define the match criteria for [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

---

For example, if you wanted to replace all occurrences of `'asc'` in a string, you could use the `g` (global) modifier on the regex.

```
th.className = th.className.replace(/asc/g,"dsc");
```

---

But given your examples, the regex used won't provide any different result than using a string `'asc'`.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the great answer! I'll be checking out that link ASAP to learn more.